# Sculpting, joining high detail meshes for 3d print

Tags: modeling, sculpting, 3d-printing, retopology, boolean-modifier

I would be very grateful for help from more experienced (than me) sculptors out there ;)

So, a little bit of a background. I wanted to make a 3d printable sculpt of my friends DnD character for her birthday. I wanted to do it because I thought that it would be a great gift and also a great excuse to finally start learning sculpting.

So, recently I have finished my sculpt and wanted to prepare it for 3d printing. But I don’t really know how to do it. I mean, I do know what needs to be done for a sculpt to be 3d print ready. It needs to be manifold and it needs to be contained to one, single mesh. But I don’t know how to do it in my sculpt and need some help/guidance.

I have finished my sculpt and I’m pretty happy with the outcome and detail.
And therein lies the problem 
I think that the best way to explain will be to provide screenshots:
[image]
[image]
[image]

I don’t really know how to deal with merging all this different meshes. I know that I can boolean them, but if two meshes are of much different density there are artifacts after boolean and smoothing them out is not always viable (for example at the base with text).

Can someone guide me on how it should be done and what is the best solution for this?

Thank you very much in advance!